# Apple rejected app asking to provide to access the location purpose string Info.plist

Tags: xamarin.forms, permissions, xamarin.ios, location, user-permissions

Message from App Store Review :

We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the location, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the location in the purpose string.
To help users make informed decisions about how their data is used, all permission request alerts need to specify how your app will use the requested information.

Next Steps

Please revise the relevant purpose string in your app’s Info.plist file to specify why your app needs access to the user's location. Make sure the purpose string includes an example of how the user's data will be used.
You can modify your app's Info.plist file using the property list editor in Xcode.

Following is my description:

Allow "AppName" to use your location?
This allows us to use your location to provide you certain features like your current location.

What exact description should I write?

Answer (score 0):

Apple store review clearly says and mean that you have to provide the Proper justification of users location

> This allows us to use your location to provide you certain features like your current location.

The above statement is not clear to approve your app from review state
You should mention that feature X(name) will be enabled and will work with high precision if we get the user location (lat/long)

Or
Feature X,Y and Z uses to provide user location based suggestion which need user location info to be colleted

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a type of News, you could use following description:

> It is convenient to recommend local news for you, so that you can use location services in your order

And here is a type of music app how to describe it for reference.

> Use your location information to recommend local exciting content for you

Otherwise if it is a type of chat app can describe it as follows:

> If not allowed, you will be unable to share your location in chats or use location-based services like Shake and People Nearby.  "AppName" also uses this info to deliver relevant search results and to keep your account safe when resgitering or logging into "AppName".

**Generally**, it depends on the function of your app. You need to describe it with **a clear reason**.